# Not able to hear voice but can hear music in YouTube

Tags: youtube, audio

I was trying to watch some video in YouTube today. I am not able to listen to what they are speaking. But whenever some music come up I am able to hear it. Why is this?

(I am using Firefox if it’s relevant.)

Comment: Are you sure this video has speech?! Do other videos exhibit the same behaviour? Perhaps you can provide a link to this video so we can check it out as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it only happen on YouTube? Does it only happen on one video?

I would check if the headphone/speaker jack is plugged in all the way and if that doesn't help, I'd try another set of headphones to see if it happens again.

Once, my headphones broke so that I couldn't hear any sound that was common on the left and right channel, only the differences. This made stereo music sound very weird… no vocals… just instruments and I couldn't listen to anything mono.

Answer (score 4):

There's a couple of things you could check:

1. Are both speakers plugged in and working? It could be that the voices are on the left channel and the music on the right (unlikely I know), and only the right speaker is working.
2. Check in another browser such as Chrome or even IE to see if there's a fault with the plugin. Reinstalling might solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

It is probably the left/right channel problem. The speech is  from one channel; and the music is from another channel.

1. Double click the **Voice Control** icon in the system tray. And make sure the **Balance** is located in the middle.
2. Try playing some other sound/music. And make sure both of your speakers are working well.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me once when using headphones. I managed to solve it by moving the headphones balance control *away* from the center.

Answer (score -2):

if you cant find the voice control it's in the bottom right of your screen by the clock it'll be the orange speaker like thing double clock that and it'll say main volume move to either all the way to left or right it fixes it

Answer (score -3):

Double click the Voice Control icon in the system tray. And make sure the Balance is located far right. This fixed it for me.

Comment: Huh? How can this help?

Comment: Making the left more than the right in balance also worked for me. Just a theory, but this might be because normally voices and music are kept separate to improve music quality, but this kind of makes the music section also play the voice section.

Comment: Edit (coz I can't edit my last comment) it works best when one is on 100 and the other is on 0. Also it doesn't matter which one is higher than the other.